# Idea cant recognize Date constructor (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, intellij-idea, typescript

i've just faced with a problem. 
Intellij Idea cant recognize Date constructor, what is wrong? 
Everything works just fine, but idea underlines the code.

Here is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Intellij underlines variables that have been defined as method parameters.  Are you sure it just doesn't recognize the type that is passed in to the Date constructor?

Comment: What is the type of `UserModel.registered`?

Comment: The type of UserModel.registered is number. Time in millis.

Answer (score 1):

It does recognized the constructor, error is appeared becouse you trying to assign `Date` to a `number` variable. Most simple (but really bad) solution is change type of `u.resistered` to `number | typeof Date`. Better way is create another variable.

Comment: Wait but JS Date has constructor with number. Explained there 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
new Date(value);

Comment: All okay with date constructor. But you can't assign construced `Date` to a `u.registered` becouse it has `number` type.